# Automatic restart of Spring Boot app after fatal exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In `node.js` world, there are apps like `Supervisor` - it's a daemon process that checks if your app is running, and if not (closed, crashed), it restarts it instantly. That's very nice way of temporary handling critical errors in production, when one feature could fail, but rest of system is still running.

I come from `PHP` background where all you had to do is to press `back` button in browser, when something is broken.

How to achieve this behavior in `Spring Boot` ? So far what I noticed is that when app faces unhandled exception, it crashes and whole server is down. I know that those kind of errors are the ones that one should fix asap, but sometimes it's just impossible, and system needs to be running.
Are there any tools that work like `Node.js` `supervisor`?

Comment: [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) doesn't seem to be node-specific, there shouldn't be anything stopping you from using it with a Spring Boot application.

Comment: The thing is... I asked this question because I wonder that this is the only way to handle fatal errors. Maybe you have other suggestions about how to recover from them without need to restart?

Answer (score 1):

In the past I sometimes used the [Java Wrapper by Tanuki](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/) which worked quite nice. Otherwise you do have the option to either monitor the process and automatically restart if it fails (dependent on your system environment) or on the highest level of you application catch Throwable, which will not be a good idea because you'll catch fatal cases that by intend should kill your jvm execution, e.g. OutOfMemory...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What are you using/doing now to prevent crashes?